# How does tcp communicate back to the application?

Tags: networking, tcp-ip

Are there standard sytem calls to send data to TCP? And back? How does TCP tell the application to send more or less?

Comment: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format." Too many? So what? Too long? Figure out a way to be brief....This is stifling a conversation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP communication is done through sockets, which you create with the `socket()` system call. Sockets are file descriptors, to all of the ways of reading from and writing to file descriptors (plus some additional system calls specific to sockets) work for sockets, and that's how you send and receive data.

As with any other file descriptor, both reads and writes can block (if the file descriptor is configured to block) or return an indication that the operation cannot proceed immediately (for non-blocking mode), and that's how flow control works.